# auto-complete username isn't working here

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, autocomplete

[How to persist the value of label after using getElementById() javascript function in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25174055/how-to-persist-the-value-of-label-after-using-getelementbyid-javascript-functi)

In the comment thread of the question, I try to type `@` followed by the username of the PO, I  don't see anything suggestions coming on top.

I was expecting something on the lines of the following image

[image]

But instead I didn't get a suggestion

[image]

Comment: Interesting - me neither. Firefox 31, linux. Could it be the hyphen?

Answer (score 9):

In your second example, there is no other user that could possibly be pinged other than the OP, so it doesn't make sense to @-mention them there. Obviously they're going to get the message. In fact, if you type out their name in that comment as you would to @-mention them, **the system will strip it out** because it is not necessary.

The list only appear if someone else, aside from you and the person who created the post, has commented on the post already. If it's only you and the OP in the comments, the @-mentions serve no purpose.